# Error Upgrading React Native version to 0.64

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

We were upgrading from 0.59.8 to 0.64 and we are getting the following error

```
ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by WebSocketModule at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:67)
```

Can anyone help out here, Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28992 seems to be discussing the issue.  In my case it was enabled by StoryBook.

This holds a promising solution though https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31397#issuecomment-831262990 but does not apply to Expo so I cannot verify.